# About Malware occupying memory

Tags: memory, malware, task-manager, tasks

Can a malware occupy memory without getting noticed by or displayed in "Windows Task Manager"? How can we detect such malware, if any? Can you give examples of such malware?

Comment: I would *assume* (I'm not very knowledgeable on the subject) that it cannot escape the `Processes` tab but it may not appear in the `Programs` tab or appear in `Processes` under a faked name. If you sort the menu by memory usage, you can easily see it *if* it is using a high amount in relation to other ones . As for your second question on how it can be detected , maybe with Windows Defender (on Win10) ? *Disclaimer : **This is all speculation***

Comment: Technically speaking, like viruses, malware can attach itself to other programs. In order to do so, it must run as administrator, something that won't happen easily nowadays anymore, so most malware runs as a standalone process, usually with a random name.

Comment: If an advanced malware works like a hypervisor, it will be almost impossible to detect it at all from inside the OS...